# Hiding/Showing rows of a Recyclerview works but takes too much time

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to hide certain rows from a recyclerview if a condition happens with a code like this in its onBindViewHolder function:

```
 if (condition)
        {
            holder.mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            holder.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 0;
            params.width = 0;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

The code does successfully hide/show the rows according to the condition, but it takes seconds just successfully display the rows in a recyclerview that contains only 21 rows, indeed it takes lower time when for each row of the recyclerview condition is true and it executes for each one **holder.mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)**;

So executing this code:

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 0;
            params.width = 0;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Is very expensive for the mobile phone.

Is there any way to achieve the same effect to hide/show rows with a code that can execute faster?

Comment: what's the point of binding items in a recyclerview if you're not going to show them ? remove them from your list of items, or don't bind them in the first place

Comment: i do'nt see why you need to set the view and height 0 of any row.. it should be hidden without that..

Comment: @RishabhRitweek, nope, for some reason if you do that it acts the same as View.INVISIBLE.

Comment: @a_local_nobody, recyclerview showing of elements is linked to the option selected on a spinner, so it looked better to load all elements first, and then, according to the selected option, you hide or show the required rows in the recyclerview.

Comment: ok so, load all elements, then filter your list of data based on selection and notify the adapter of changes

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't filter your RecyclerView this way, here's the reason why:

The recycler view works by only inflating as many views as needed. So if there are only 8 views visible on the screen, it will only inflate give-or-take 10 views so that scrolling looks good. It will recycler the views that went out of the screen and rebind them with new data.

Now if you filter your list by setting the views' visibility to gone, then the recycler view won't be able to recycle this view, as it's still technically in the visible portion of the screen, so it has to inflate more views, to show the other items. By only binding the filtered data to the recycler view it won't have to create soo many views, and thus it will be much more efficient.

So yeah, as others have mentioned it, you should really filter your data, and let the recycler view handle the rest. It will be much more performant this way.